# Web Animations API add one anime to many elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

it is possible made code bellow using only Web Animations API? I don't like use included library, so I try use Web Animations API, but I can't find how Can I created one animations which include few elements.

```
var tl = anime.timeline({
  easing: 'linear',
  loop: true
});

tl
.add({
  targets: '.button-scroll-icon',
  height: ["100%", "0%"],
  duration: 500
})
.add({
  targets: '.button-scroll-icon',
  opacity: [1, 0],
  duration: 10
})
.add({
  targets: '.button-scroll-icon',
  height: ["0%", "100%"],
  duration: 10
})
.add({
  targets: '.button-scroll-wheel',
  translateY: 15,
  opacity: [1, 0],
  duration: 500
}, '-=520')
.add({
  targets: '.button-scroll',
  translateY: 10,
  duration: 500
}, '-=520')
.add({
  targets: '.button-scroll-text',
  opacity: [1, 0.5],
  duration: 500
}, '-=520')
.add({
  targets: '.button-scroll',
  translateY: 0,
  duration: 500
})
.add({
  targets: '.button-scroll-icon',
  opacity: [0, 1],
  duration: 500
}, '-=500')
.add({
  targets: '.button-scroll-text',
  opacity: [0.5, 1],
  duration: 500
}, '-=500');
```

Comment: So even elements that are not into the DOM at the moment the animation starts would get targeted if inserted while the animation runs? I believe this is not possible (well you could make it with a MutationObserver, but that's probably not worth the trouble). KeyframeEffects only have one target, so you'd need to create one such Animation per element (or pseudo-element). Also what does `'-=520'` means here?

Comment: "-=520" - It is mean "Start animation 500ms early". There has to be a way :(